# no suitable servers found when trying to connect to mongodb on R

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I am receiving this error randomly after trying to connect to mongodb atlas via the mongolite package.

```
library(mongolite)

url = "myurl"
data = mongo(collection = "mycollection", db = "mydb", url = url)
```

```
Error: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-00.skqv5.mongodb.net:27017'] [TLS handshake failed: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-01.skqv5.mongodb.net:27017'] [TLS handshake failed: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate
```

I was able to connect every day for the past few weeks. When I run this on other PC's, it works. I have also tried running it on RStudio cloud and it works. Something seems to be happening locally that I do not understand. I have seen other posts that have this error but I don't understand how to do this in R.

Comment: Also stuck on this, did you get anywhere?

Comment: mongo(collection = "mycollection", db = "mydb", url = url, options = ssl_options(weak_cert_validation = TRUE))

Comment: Thanks @niceguy. I fixed it, I hadn't set up my mongodb with the IP address of my laptop.